# Js slides.length. How to display all images in the slideshow

Tags: javascript

My slideshow consists of 8 images but only one is displayed. I figure out it is something to do with slides.length but i just don't know how exactly to alter it. My js code is as below.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);

function init(){
'use strict';

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);


function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 console.log(slides.length);
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
 
 console.log(slides,slides.length,slideIndex-1,slides[0]);
  
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some problems I've noticed:

- You only run this code once, so the slides won't get updated.
- You never increase or decrease slideIndex

What you can do:

- Run this on a timer to update every few seconds or on a button click
- Increase the slideIndex each time to allow the slide to change.

If you are still having trouble, please give us a bit more information. Good luck

Comment: Please check my comment below. wasn#t able to put it all in direct response.

Answer (score 0):

been fighting to get a  solution, sorry took a while but i came up with something to increase/decrease the slideshows? I however can't resize the images(they appear too big on the slideshow)! I also can't have the first image displayed! The images on appear onclick. here is the new js code.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);


function init(){
'use strict';

var slideIndex = 0; //first img
 
var prev=document.querySelector('[class="prev"]'); //get arrow
var next=document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0]; //get arrow

/*invoke function with clicl on arrow*/
next.addEventListener('click',
           function(){showSlides(slideIndex)});



function showSlides() {
 //console.log(slideIndex);
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 //console.log(slides.length);
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} //wenn ende erreicht, dann von vorn
 
  else slideIndex++;
 //console.log(slideIndex);
  
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "none";
 slides[slideIndex].style.display="block";
  
 
 dots[slideIndex].className += " active";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {

var slideShow = function () {
    var i;
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].setAttribute("style","display:none");
    }
    count++;
    if (count > slides.length) { count = 1; }
    slides[count-1].setAttribute("style","display:block");
    setTimeout(slideShow, 3600);
}

var count = 0;
slideShow();
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation how this code works. It would be helpful for people with similar issues while not being so familiar with javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* ...then execute the content of the referenced FN */
    'use strict';

    function showData() {
        var info = document.getElementById('info');
        var selctedImg = this;
        var html = '<b>Alle Informationen des Bildes:</b>';
        html += '<ul>';
        html += '<li><b>src-Attribut:</b><br>' + selctedImg.src + '</li>';
        html += '<li><b>alt-Attribut:</b><br>' + selctedImg.alt + '</li>';
        html += '<li><b>title-Attribut:</b><br>' + selctedImg.title + '</li>';
        html += '<li><b>id-Attribut:</b><br>' + selctedImg.id + '</li>';
        html += '</ul>';

        info.innerHTML = html;
    }


    var img = document.getElementById('images').getElementsByTagName('img');
    console.log(img);

    /* Bind the event handlers.
    After this code block an information [ev] or [event] can be seen at the img element in the input sector of the browser */
    for (var index = 0; index < img.length; index++) {
        img[index].onmouseover = showData;
    }
```

Comment: another great alternative from the DOM method.